# Android - check if user has purchased InApp product from a different package

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing

Context: I used to have an app on the Play Store that allowed users to buy an in-app product to get rid of the ads. I had to re-upload the app as a new package. The old app is still up, but I have unpublished it.

Question: From the new app, how can I check if the user had bought an in-app product in the old app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible. The in-app purchases are directly tied to the unique package-id used when the applications were first created.